# Jquery or javascript event on document header load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any Jquery or javascript event available on document header load and not on document load ?

I created two sites,

1. desktop.example.com is for desktop and
2. m.example.com for mobile version.

Actually I want to detect user-agent and depending on it redirect page to mobile or desktop version of site.

Comment: Just put the JavaScript in the header. It will be executed when it is parsed (which is before the `body` of the document).

Comment: Why are you doing this on the client and not the server? Nothing like two page renders instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for an event to trigger your redirect. Just place it directly in the `<head>` element.  In most cases the body won't even be rendered before it redirects.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Yes, right now I did the same thing but still I am looking that event, because current solution load some html markup before redirection

Comment: its impossible to redirect any quicker looking for an event, because the script that listens for the event is still going to be loaded and parsed in the head tag.